# how to make a type that supports short or unsigned..etc modifiers c++

Tags: c++, class, types, unsigned

I am trying to make type in c++ and what am trying to do is:
here is an example:
this is a type i made called bbool.

```
class bbool
    {
public:
    bbool();
    bbool(unsigned short int);
private:
    bool x = false,
        y = false,
        z = false;
    unsigned short int a, b;
    void check(unsigned short int);
};

void bbool::check(unsigned short int c){
    if ( c < 0 || c >= 3 ){
        throw invalid_argument("Wrong value::Not 1, 2 or 3");
    }
}

bbool::bbool(){

}

bbool::bbool(unsigned short int c){
    check(c);
    switch ( c )
    {
        case 0:
            x = true;
            break;
        case 1:
            y = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            z = true;
            break;
        }
   }
```

and what I want to be able to do is if possible

```
unsigned bbool x;
```

and to be able to define what the modifires unsigned or short or .. etc do.  i found "that i must to make a group!!??" (not so sure what it means). and btw is the "unsigned typeA" different than "typeA" (not in value like (int x
positive or negative value or unsigned postive only) like if it have a different class)

thanks in advance and please forgive me if it is not a good question.

Comment: As far as I know, you can not make unsigned user-types in C++

Comment: What about making it a template? `bbool<unsigned>` is possible.

Comment: is there any other way? other than "unsigned"  or etc.

Comment: i think i will go for the template

Comment: `unsigned` is just an abbreviation of `unsigned int`, `short` for `short int` etc. And the only non-int type that can be modified like this is `signed/unsigned char`. These are all fundamental types, not class types. (In C++, all classes are types but not all types are classes)